# Using Moles with XUnit - wrong dll version

Tags: .net, dll, xunit, moles, pex-and-moles

I'm trying to set up Moles to use in our unit testing. We are using xunit, so I am `using` the Xunit extension that comes with moles (`Microsoft.Moles.Framework.Xunit`). However, as we are running Xunit 1.7, Moles is complaining that I am not running Version 1.6.1.1521 (with a `FileLoadException`).

The [Moles Manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molesmanual.pdf) (page 28) does say:

> **xUnit.net Version:**
>
> > 1.5.0.1479 (for other xUnit.net versions, recompile the attribute from sources)

This is where I get stuck - is the source code for this xunit extension available somewhere? Or will I have to use the specific version of xunit that Moles requires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While proxon's answer was very helpful for getting my task done, allow me to present a better answer I found as I investigated further (to hopefully help others coming across this problem). The source code is found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\Documentation\moles.samples.zip`. Pretty much identical to the code that proxon decompiled, of course.

You can also find the NUnit and MbUnit wrappers in there.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you define a assembly binding redirect in the `moles.runner.exe.config`?

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity
                    name="xunit.dll"
                    publicKeyToken="8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.5.0.1479" newVersion="1.6.1.1521" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to recompile then you can do it. I looked for Moles source code but I couldn't find it anywhere. Then I tried to disassemble **Microsoft.Moles.Xunit.dll** and I realized that the attribute is just few lines long.

MoledAttribute source code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using XUnit;

namespace Microsoft.Moles.Framework.Xunit
{
    public sealed class MoledAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
    {
        // Fields
        private IDisposable _molesContext;

        public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
        {
            this._molesContext = MolesContext.Create();
        }

        public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
        {
            IDisposable disposable = this._molesContext;
            if (disposable != null)
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
            this._molesContext = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You should create a new class library and add reference to your **xunit.dll** of any version you want. It should even work with 1.8.0.1545 as I haven't noticed any changes to **XUnit.BeforeAfterTestAttribute** which is the only depencency.